# How can I refactor this code in javascript?

Tags: javascript

**I have this code and I need to refactor that**

> I tried creating a new function and passing it through reduce but It doesn't work

```js
function fx(n) {
  let d= (new Array(n+1)).join('x').split('').reduce((d,v,i)=>{
  let J=2*i+1+(i&1)
  return d += J+(J+1-2*i+1)
  },-1-Math.floor(n/2) * 2);
  return d-(n-2);
};
```

Comment: What's the function doing / what's it calculating? Please provide more clarity.

Comment: It is a challenge but I also don't understand what is going on :(

Comment: Where is it from?

Comment: It was a company challenge to get the job but I couldn't do this very well so, i'm studying :(

Comment: So you want to use another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Yes That's what i want!

Comment: @SagadeGeminis Just curious, could you tell me more about the company and the challenge? if you don't mind :)

Comment: @SagadeGeminis you can check my answer.

Comment: Sure it's a japanese company called flagship

Comment: @SagadeGeminis ok thanks

Comment: Thanks to you! it was a nice solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what it should be doing.

```js
const squareIncrement = number => Math.pow(Math.abs(number) + 1, 2);
```